# Role of headers in .NET managed modules to create assemblies

Tags: .net, .net-assembly

I am a newbie to CLR and I am referring to the book CLR via C# by Jeffrey Richter. The book states that the compilation of source code using CLR-compliant compiler is done as follow:
[image]

*Takeaway*: the compiler generates **only the IL code and metadata** of managed modules

Quoting from the book:

> A managed module is a standard 32-bit Windows portable
>   executable (PE32) file or a standard 64-bit Windows portable executable (PE32+) file that requires the
>   CLR to execute.

The following components are listed as a part of a managed module:

> PE32 or PE32+ header
>
> CLR header
>
> Metadata
>
> IL code

*My understanding:* Compiler generates just a part of the managed module (IL code and Metadata).

---

Generating assemblies:
According to the book, **IL and metadata** of the managed modules, along with resources files, are used to generate an assembly
[image]

According to this [Microsoft document about assemblies in CLR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/assemblies-in-the-common-language-runtime), The managed module in itself is not executable

> Microsoft intermediate language (MSIL) code in a portable executable (PE) file will not be executed if it does not have an associated assembly manifest.

My understanding of the framework is as follows:

The managed modules cannot be run independently

Managed modules form building blocks for assemblies

Only the IL code and metadata are used for creating an assembly.

**Question:** If the managed modules serve just one purpose - being a part of an assembly and the assembly uses just the IL code and metadata of a module, what is the use of having PE32(+) and CLR headers in the managed module?

The answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/10065485/3574404 explains that PE32 files can contain much more than assemblies but it does not answer my questions.

Comment: Microsoft needed a container format to package the managed module(s).  One that was easily understood by existing tooling.  They chose the PE32 format.  Never designed for managed code, but flexible enough to be adoptable.  Compare to Java .jar files, actually a .zip file.  The PE32 header is necessary to make it a PE32 format file, the CLR header identifies some crucial properties of the assembly, like the CLR version that is needed to load the assembly.  A file format exists for just the IL+metadata, it is .netmodule.  But can't be executed until it is packaged into a PE32 assembly.

Comment: @HansPassant CLR header makes sense for the assembly. I fail to understand the role of CLR header component of the managed module PE32 file. Is it used when creating an assembly containing the module? Because the book shows that only the IL code and the metadata are used.

Comment: It is written when the assembly is created.  The diagrams skip a bit too fast, it doesn't show the role of the linker.  It is the linker that generates the PE32 file, formatting it correctly and adding the CLR header and module(s).  The linker is not very visible in .NET tooling, it is built into the C# compiler for example.  But also available as a separate tool, it is al.exe.  Since it is rarely used it is not talked about much.